# Showing point in f(x) such that f'(x)=0 exists

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, rolles-theorem, stationary-point

let $f(x)=x^4 + \sin x$

Show that there exists $x \in (-2,2)$ such that $f'(x) = 0$.

Comment: Hint: mean value theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem

Comment: Warning: You got 3 hints so far but each of them describes a different way to solve the problem. So don't try to combine these hints.

Answer (score 2):

**Guide:**
Show that
$$
f'(2)>0\quad f'(-2)<0
$$
and conclude using the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I think i overcomplicated the question. So by IVT we know there must exist x in (-2,2) such that f'(x)=0 ?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $f(\frac{\pi}{2}), f(-\frac{\pi}{2})> 0$, $f(0)=0$.